# How can I dynamically access a global variable in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

In browser-based JavaScript, you can do something like this:

```
var foo = "foo";

(function() {
    var foo = "bar";

    console.log(foo);
    // => "bar"

    console.log(window["foo"]);
    // => "foo"
})();
```

Is there any way to do something similar in Node, which lacks a `window` object?

Comment: You can create a function called Globals and assign the variable to Globals.foo

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

Comment: This is just a bad thing to design.  Don't use local variables with the same name as higher level scoped variables that you want to ask.  Just pick original names and you don't have this problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an environment agnostic approach, for example, when writing code to work on both the browser and Node.js, you can do something like this in [global code](https://es5.github.io/#x10.1) at the top of your JavaScript file:

```
var globalObject = typeof global === "undefined" ? this : global;
```

and then use `globalObject` similar to how you would [`window` in the browser context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) and as you would use [`global` in the Node.js context](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html).

Note that you must declare a variable without `var` for it to be part of the `global` object in Node.js.

Comment: And what/where is the global context in Node.js?

Comment: @FelixKling Regardless of whether you're dealing with the browser or Node.js, ["Global code is source text that is treated as an ECMAScript Program. The global code of a particular Program does not include any source text that is parsed as part of a FunctionBody."](https://es5.github.io/#x10.1)

Comment: Sure, but typical Node.js apps are split into modules. Are you saying that inside a module, `this` refers to the global object?

Comment: Then you are wrong. Inside a module, `this` refers to `exports`.

Comment: @FelixKling Try it for yourself in the node REPL, `this === global` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: The REPL is not a module. Create a module, log `this === global` and `require` it. Only inside the "main script" `this === global` (e.g. if you run `node main.js`). A module is not in the global context. Your answer is  correct, I'm just concerned that not everybody knows what the global context in a Node.js app is.

Comment: Regarding your edit: `var global = global || this;` won't work inside modules. It's equivalent to `var global; global = global || this;`. I.e. it creates a *local* variable `global` and just assigns `this` afterwards.

Comment: @FelixKling OK, thanks for the clarification, you are correct, I am in the process of fixing my incorrect answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can access global variables using `global` keyword in nodejs.

**Note:-** There is one rule in `nodejs` only those variables willl be global variables which dose not have declared using `var`.

Like if you have declareation like bellow

```
foo = "sample"; //this you can access using global
```

But

```
var foo = "sample"; //this you cann't access using global.
```

The second one is not actually in global scope, it's local to that module.

From [node global docs](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html)

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that
>   in browsers if you're in the global scope var something will define a
>   global variable. In Node this is different. The top-level scope is not
>   the global scope; var something inside a Node module will be local to
>   that module.